# cannot load 'rails.application.database_configuration' undefined method'[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I changed my database.yml to use sqlite3 database in test and developement and postgresql in production. My application run fine in production but when I launch test or development environements i have this error :

```
Cannot load 'Rails.application.database_configuration':
undefined method'[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethoError)
```

my database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
  adapter: postgresql
  host: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:host]%>
  database: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:name]%>
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:username]%>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password]%>
```

Answer (score -8, accepted):

```
host: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:host]%>
database: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:name]%>
username: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:username]%>
password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password]%>
```

Oh Lord, don't do this.  Don't do this for many reasons.

Use `ENV` vars on the production server instead:

```
host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSEWORD'] %>
```

Then you want to go onto your prod server and set those variables in your shell config file (.bashrc, .zshrc, .profile) as follows:

```
export DB_HOST=your_host
export DB_NAME=your_name
export DB_USER=your_user
export DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

Your issue is 1 of 2 possible things:

a. A race condition where the database configs are being loaded prior to the secrets file.

b. You have your secrets.yml segmented be environments and do not have those nodes for development/test environments.

Comment: thanks to put me in the good rails, the cause was the missing node in secrets.yml

Comment: so.. it boils down to adding a `database` section for `development` and `test` environments in `secrets.yml`. right?

Comment: I'm using `ENV` variables for database connection and I 've put my settings inside `secrets.yml`.. however when run `rails s` and try to access the rails app I get this error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.. Any ideas?

Comment: While you may have solved the immediate problem, using ENV for secrets is a bad idea (despite being shockingly popular). For more: http://movingfast.io/articles/environment-variables-considered-harmful/

Comment: @Lykos that means that the command-line invocation of mysql doesn't see a password, which in this case could mean that the password is not being quoted and some funky characters (e.g., '#', '&', etc.) are being interpreted by your shell.

Answer (score 10):

Ran into this with the new Rails 5.1.0 with adding my variables in with the new secrets encrypted file.

Your nil is happening because even though it is development it still tries to load everything and you are calling things from nil -> something[:nil][:cant_grab_from_nil]. The quick workaround is an if statement. Only suggest this when using the secrets encrypted file in the new Rails 5.1.

```
production:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
  adapter: postgresql
  <% if Rails.application.secrets[:database].present? %>
    host: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:host]%>
    database: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:name]%>
    username: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:username]%>
    password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password]%>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: it should be documented well

Answer (score 2):

## Aside About Security

If you're going to go this route, which is fine, you need to make sure of one very important thing:

> Your secrets.yml file is securely provisioned, not checked into source control, and not readable by anybody who shouldn't have
>   access

In that case it's no less secure than having a locked-down `*key/*crt` certificate file for your web server, except that you're potentially storing multiple secrets. Doing this *correctly* is preferable to putting secrets in `ENV`, but there are better options still.

Some further reading:

- http://movingfast.io/articles/environment-variables-considered-harmful/
- http://elasticcompute.io/2016/01/21/runtime-secrets-with-docker-containers/ (obvs ignore Docker-specific stuff)

## Your Actual Problem

Your problem is @tagCincy's second idea ("b"), and oddly enough, this is super easy to fix. Just do what @Nik-Olai suggested. Declare (albeit blank) values of the same parameters in your dev/test environments like this:

```
development:
  ...
  database:
    :name:
    :username:
    :password:

test:
  # same thing here
```

The reason is that, while the `production` database configuration doesn't get used in `development` or `test` environments, ***parsing*** of that configuration will still happen.

Put a different way, your production database settings will still get parsed (and ERB-interpreted) even in test/dev mode.

`Rails.application.secrets` is environment-dependent, so in dev and test modes `Rails.application.secrets[:database]` won't exist, which means that the subsequent `[]` call will hit a nil target, and voila!

Comment: I think there is a missing a "Solutions" section lol